# Change the menu bar icon of WhatPulse

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I'd like to make the WhatPulse icon white to make it match the rest of the icons in Yosemite dark mode.

I've looked in the package contents of WhatPulse.app, but I don't find any images in the resources. Does anyone know where they're hidden?

Comment: WhatPulse isn't a native app and doesn't seem to use the standard OS X menu bar item framework (+1)

Comment: Would you have an idea where else the resources could be hidden?